# Gradle doesn't seem to be resolving my project dependency properly

Tags: java, gradle

I'm pretty new to Gradle and am having an issue getting my a module that is dependant on another module to build properly.

So I have the following configuration for my modules.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    }
}

project(':web-service') {
    apply plugin: 'war'

    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
        compile('com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:1.7')
        compile('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1')
    }
}

project(':core') {
    dependencies {
        compile('log4j:log4j:1.2.17')
    }

}
```

If I try to build my `core` project everything succeeds as expected.

However, if I try to build the `web-service` project with the following command:

```
gradle :web-service:build
```

It appears to build the `core` project first as expected but then encounter build errors that indicate that classes that exist in the `core` module cannot be found.

What gives?

Comment: What task does it fail on? Compiling main or test code? Something else?

Comment: It fails on the `compileJava` task of the `:web-service` module after compiling the `:core` module. It's complaining about missing symbols which reside in the `:core` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was completely my fault. I dug deeper on the error messages that I was getting and found some `package does not exist` messages at the top. Turns out that my directory structure was not inline with my package names.